# PostBackUrl doesn't set Page.IsCrossPagePostBack to true

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback

I have a legacy application at my hand which uses ASP.NET WebForms.

My problem here is that, `LinkButton` controls doesn't set the `Page.IsCrossPagePostBack` to true. In this application, there are 6 `LinkButton` controls which are used to create related entities (they post back to a different page than the action of the form element). This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscrosspagepostback.aspx) claims that PostBackUrl causes Page.IsCrossPagePostBack to become true. But in my code, this is not the case. It always returns false.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit counterintuitive, but you have to read very carefully:

> In either case, the PreviousPage page property will contain an object that represents the previous or originator page. If, for example, Page A posts to Page B, ***Page A's*** IsCrossPagePostBack property (accessible through the PreviousPage property) will be true and Page B's PreviousPage property will have the name of Page A.

So the solution is:

```
    if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
        // do stuff
```